# Bind a function to get the class of a sortable item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using [Jquery UI Sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) to interchange items from two lists. I need to get the class from an item when it is moved from one list to another which is easy enough to do like this.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
            alert($(ui.item).attr('class'));
        }
});
```

But I need to do this on dynamic content so I need to to bind this function with .on to make it work. So how I can do something like this..

```
$(document).on("sortable","#sortable", function() {
```

and still access the api `update` option to make this work?

Comment: Use $("#sortable li).on(); ?

Comment: That's the wrong version of bind to use for dynamic content.

Comment: Oh sorry misunderstood your question

Comment: when your content changes you could call $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: I don't see the point of that. Could you provide an answer with example?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic content ? What changes ? Maybe i misunderstood the question, so please provide more details.

Comment: The lists are in a template called with ajax. So I have to use the delegate version of .on() to do anything with them.

Comment: Why not apply `sortable` in ajax success ? If it's not ok for your application logic, you could use amplify's publish/subscribe methods.

Comment: What content on your page is dynamic?  Are you adding new lists?  New elements in the list?  (P.S. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID)

Comment: The event is called `sortupdate`.  http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

Comment: You can't dynamically apply `.sortable()` to new elements.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/ ,the events tag. i took this example for there:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    sort: function( event, ui ) {
          //do stuff
     }
});
```

This event is triggered during sorting, you can also bind events on stop, before stop and start, check it.